# Function expected at GoogleAnalytics.prototype.startTrackerWithId

Tags: ionic-framework, google-analytics

I tried to use GoogleAnalytics.prototype.startTrackerWithId but I got "Function expected" error:
TypeError: Function expected
   at GoogleAnalytics.prototype.startTrackerWithId

I used console.log(this.ga.startTrackerWithId) to check it and received following which shows it is a function:

```
function (id, interval) { return Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ionic_native_core__["cordova"])(this, "startTrackerWithId", { "successIndex": 2, "errorIndex": 3 }, arguments); }
```

And this is my code:

```
-------------------------app.module.ts:

...

import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics/ngx';

...

@NgModule({

...

providers: [
    ...
    GoogleAnalytics
  ]

...


--------------------------home.ts:

...

import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics/ngx';

...

constructor(..., private ga: GoogleAnalytics) {
  }

testLog(){

  ...

console.log(this.ga.startTrackerWithId);

this.ga.startTrackerWithId('UA-...',30) 

   .then(() => {

     alert("Google analytics is ready now");

      this.ga.trackView('test');

    })

   .catch(e => {console.log('Error starting GoogleAnalytics', e);});

  }

}
```

would you please guide me how to use GoogleAnalytics in IONIC projects?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just uninstall @ionic-native/google-analytics and install version 4 instead:
npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/google-analytics
npm install --save @ionic-native/google-analytics@4

I should also import GoogleAnalytics from @ionic-native/google-analytics instead of @ionic-native/google-analytics/ngx (because of version down grade).
And finally it works without error.